# Has any NFL team ever gone an entire season without trailing by 7 or more points?

Tags: american-football, nfl, history

According to [this article](https://www.espn.com/blog/nfcnorth/post/_/id/24165/rewind10-the-packers-and-7-point-deficits), the 2010 Green Bay Packers and 1962 Detroit Lions went the entire season without ever trailing in a game by more than 7 points.  (Did any other teams accomplish that?)

Has there ever been an NFL team whose largest deficit in one season was 6 points or less?

Comment: I mean, any teams that fit your criteria would be included in that article...

Comment: I'm asking about the entire history of the NFL, not just back to 1962.

Comment: What you're asking then, is if someone will scour through 50+ years of football data to try to figure out some incredibly obscure record from games played before detailed stats were kept on each game...  I wouldn't count on this question getting any good answer.